# parrot VM on linux

Tags: linux, .net

Any Linux distros or applications that mainly use/run on parrot vm?

I"m asking because in windows, there is .NET and libraries written in C#, F#, VB will work together. parrot can do the same. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

So why aren't Linux application development using this?
Won't it be better if there's some kind of unified development model/platform?

Comment: Apps written in plain old C have "worked together" for ages on Unix (and Windows). What would be the benefit of having everything run under a VM?

Comment: I could think of one reason. Someone can write a library in his programming language and others can use it without needing to use the same language.

Comment: Perl6 (and parrot) is still somewhat experimental. But look at the parrot/perl6 site, they are the autoritative source on their matters.